Troubleshooting a Spark Docker Cluster Setup with Jupyter Lab
I am trying to setup a simple spark docker cluster with jupyter lab container to run some tests. Here is the docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  jupyterlab:
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:spark-3.5.0
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"  # JupyterLab
    volumes:
      - ./data:/home/jovyan/data  # Mount a local directory to the container for persistent storage
    environment:
      - JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes


  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.5.0
    container_name: spark-master
    volumes:
      - ./config/spark-defaults.conf:/opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
      - "4040:4040"
    environment:
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-master
      - SPARK_MASTER_IP=${EXTERNAL_IP}
      - SPARK_MODE=master


  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.5.0
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "7000"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-worker
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_DRIVER_HOST=${EXTERNAL_IP}

And my simple script that I try to run in Jupyter Notebook is:
!pip install findspark
import findspark
findspark.init()
 
import logging
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,FloatType,IntegerType,StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json,col
try:
    spark_session = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .master("spark://spark-master:7077") \
            .appName("SparkTest") \
            .getOrCreate()
    spark_session.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")
    logging.info('Spark session created successfully')
except Exception:
    logging.error("Couldn't create the spark session")
 
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=2, b=3., c='string2', d=date(2000, 2, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=4, b=5., c='string3', d=date(2000, 3, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
])
df.show()

The error I get is when df.show() is executed:
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 28
     22 from pyspark.sql import Row
     23 df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
     24     Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
     25     Row(a=2, b=3., c='string2', d=date(2000, 2, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
     26     Row(a=4, b=5., c='string3', d=date(2000, 3, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
     27 ])
---> 28 df.show()

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:959, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    953     raise PySparkTypeError(
    954         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
    955         message_parameters={"arg_name": "vertical", "arg_type": type(vertical).__name__},
    956     )
    958 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 959     print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    960 else:
    961     try:

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7) (192.168.112.4 executor 0): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/conda/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory

I don't know what does conda have to do here. Any help is appreciated.
